# How to use like expression of datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

I want to add new column 'temp' into datatable with following below

```
datatable.Columns.Add(
    'temp', typeof(string), 
    "Convert(IFF(" + column + 
    " like '%#' == True ,'isTrue','isFalse'), 'System.String')");
```

but I get an error: "The expression contains undefined function call IFF()."

Answer (score 8):

Simple typo: `IFF` should be `IIF`.

I also think there's something wrong with your conditional expression in your IIF statement.  Try this instead:

```
datatable.Columns.Add("temp", typeof(string), 
                     "Convert(IIF(" + column + " like '%#','isTrue','isFalse'), 'System.String')");
```

Comment: ...but corrected it, so a +1 I guess. But why the extra quoting stuff?